# Does function work with global variables so well like local variables?

Tags: javascript, html

When I place all the variables (`box2`, `display`, `total`, `error`) in the function, the code works but when I place them outside the function, it doesn't work. I suppose it should work because all of these 4 variables are global variables and the function must recognize them (the variables). Please I would be very happy if someone could come out and explain why the code isn't working.

```js
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
var display = document.getElementById("display");
var total = Number(box1) + Number(box2);
var error = "There is a problem with the input fields";


function cal() {
  if (!isNaN(box1) && !isNaN(box2)) {
    display.innerHTML = "$" + total;
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = error;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Best Addiction Calculator</h1>
<input class="field" placeholder="type first number" type="text" id="box1">
<input class="field" placeholder="type second number" type="text" id="box2">
<button style="font-size:xx-large; color:#860EED" onClick="cal()">Calculate</button>
<p id="display">i</p>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What made you want to move the variables out of the function in the first place? Since it was working with them in it (which is where they belong)?

Comment: Hi. It's because of learning purposes. I was taught that global variables would respond irrespective of where it's called from. Thanks!

Comment: I know of that already. I am just hesitating to see if I might get another convincing answer. I am a little bit confused here; your example isn't even working for me, sir.

Please just come again and explain why it isn't working in laymen's terms.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't where the *variables* are, it's *when* you're setting their values.

This code:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
```

reads the value from the inputs **when it runs**. You want to read their values when the user clicks the button.

You **could** do this, but it wouldn't be reasonable:

```
// JUST AN EXAMPLE, DON'T ACTUALLY DO IT
var box1;
var box2;
var display;
var total;
var error;

function cal() {
    box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
    box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
    display = document.getElementById("display");
    total = Number(box1) + Number(box2);
    error = "There is a problem with the input fields";

    if (!isNaN(box1) && !isNaN(box2)) {
        display.innerHTML = "$" + total;
    } else {
        display.innerHTML = error;
    }
}
```

That demonstrates that the problem isn't where the variables are, but rather when you set their values.

But you **wouldn't do that** without a good reason. Since there's no reason for having these variables outside the function, put them in the function. In general, give a variable the most narrow scope it can have.

**If** looking up the elements were an expensive operation that you only wanted to do once (it isn't, `getElementById` is extremely fast), you could look up the elements once but then get their values within `cal`:

```
var box1 = document.getElementById("box1");              // Note no `.value` here
var box2 = document.getElementById("box2");              // Or here
var display = document.getElementById("display");

function cal() {
    var total = Number(box1.value) + Number(box2.value); // Note change on this line
    var error = "There is a problem with the input fields";

    if (!isNaN(box1) && !isNaN(box2)) {
        display.innerHTML = "$" + total;
    } else {
        display.innerHTML = error;
    }
}
```

Comment: As T.J. said, it is about **when** the `getElementById` is executing. It appears that you are loading your JS somewhere in the document before the `box1`, `box2` and `display` elements appear in the document, which is why when you assign them in a global scope it does not find the elements, they don't exist in the document yet. If your script tag was below them in the markup, `getElementById` would find them. This and [some other loading performance reasons](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) are why I always put my script tags at the end of the document.

Comment: @UselessCode: His script may well have been below his elements, but reading the value before the user input it... :-)

Comment: True, if you are directly reading the `.value`, not just caching the DOM node for later it won't work. I forgot he was doing that in the original code; it never would have occurred to me to do that. One of those cases of reading the code as you would have written it instead of what is actually there ;-) That brings up the importance of choosing good variable names. When I see `box1`, I assume it holds a reference to the DOM node named `box1`, not the value of the node. If the variable holds the value, a name like `value1` or `operand1` might make the code more readable.

Comment: @UselessCode: True that.